# Securing a hosting with SSL

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl, hosting, web-hosting

I've got a hosting server (Windows Server 2008 + IIS7) where I'm hosting tens of sites... some of them need to be secured with SSL.

For now I've opened a new IP and certificate for each such site - but as more and more sites need HTTPS, I'm looking for a better solution.

Any ideas how I can use a server certificate for all the site? or some other solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the SSL negotiation happens before the HTTP header is transmitted. This means that, at the time the server needs to pick a certificate and key pair for certifying its authority, the only information it has about what host the client is attempting to reach is the IP address.

There is no viable solution around this problem for IIS 7. In IIS 8, you'll be able to use Server Name Indication (an extension to TLS) to work around it but even then it will only work with newest clients.

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication)

Comment: Thanks :) bad news, but very helpful.

Comment: +1 for a good answer!

Answer (score 0):

One option is the Server Name Indication which Stephane mentioned.

Another options is UCC (aka SAN) certificates ([see this explanation](http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm)).
Surprisingly, on [GoDaddy SSL plans](http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/ssl-certificates.aspx) you can have get up to 100 domains in one certificate.

But probably you can obtain such certificates **only** if you own the domains for all the sites you host.